# Laravel Validate if there is already a record with similar combination of two columns

Tags: php, laravel-5

For example, I have an auction where Users can bid on items.

When a user creates a new bid I want to be sure that this user didn't bid on this item before.

The `BID` table structure is `id`, `item_id`, `user_id`, `price`. So basically I need to check if there is a record that has same `item_id` and same `user_id` at the same time.

Is there any way to do this using Laravels Validator?

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'item_id'  => 'unique:item_id,user_id,NULL,id,'. auth()->user()->id,
            'price'    => 'required|integer'
        ]);
```

The error I have:

> Undefined offset: 1

Comment: You can put unique validation for two table keys.

Comment: Try This

$id = $this->id ?: 'NULL';
$rule['item_id'] = 'unique:bids,item_id,' . $id . ',id,user_id,' . $this->user_id;

Comment: @Anshul can you write your answer more detailed?

Comment: Have you tried Raushan's answer? go through this link https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-to-check-for-unique-column-combanation-from-the-validation-rule . If not worked kindly let me know.

Comment: @Anshul I have updated my question using Raushan`s answer

Comment: Replace auth()->user()->id with $this->id

Comment: @Anshul I have an error =  `Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\BidController::$id`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178829/discussion-between-anshul-and-dmitry-malys).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-unique):

```
[
    'item_id' => 'unique:bids,item_id,null,id,user_id,' . auth()->id(),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a model for Users table.

Now,

```
 $itemIds= User:: where ('user_id',$userId)->pluck('item_Id');
 foreach($itemIds as $itemId){
      if ($itemId == $newItemId) {
            // write code if item id is already present
      } 
      else {
            // write code if item id is not present
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use laravel unique validation as

```
'user_id' => 'unique:item_id,user_id,NULL,id,'.$user->id
```

Comment: Can you show how it will look for `'item_id' => ` ?